# Jython for WEbsphere: referring to directory of jars

Tags: websphere, jython

I have a directory of jars. How can I tell my appplication / server to use all of them in its classpath?

I can use shared lib reference.
But, is it also possible to use the classpath option - for example - like this: 'C:\myFolder\' or 'C:\myFolder*.jar'.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "the classpath option"?  A WAS shared library IS an option for managing the classpath for applications in the server.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 6 (and later) you can actually include foo/bar/* in the classpath to refer to "all the jars in foo/bar".